# I am trying to concatenate the first name and last name of my user to add it as an item in his profile inside the Firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4.2

Below the code, I try but I get an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData',
>   reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at
>   fullName. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString,
>   NSDictionary, and NSArray.'

```
newUserReference.setValue(
    [
     "eMail": self.EmailOu.text!,
     "firstName": self.NameOu.text!,
     "lastName": self.LastNameOu.text!,
     "studentId": self.StudentIDOu.text!,
     "Parking Zone": self.SignUpLabel.text!,
     "fullName": self.NameOu.text! += self.LastNameOu.text!,
     "uId": uidINT
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this

```
self.NameOu.text! += self.LastNameOu.text!
```

is the issue. So take a look at this code to concatenate the name (there are about 1000 ways)

```
let firstName = "Frank"
let lastName = "Zappa"
let fullName = firstName + " " + lastName
print(fullName)  //just so you can see the concatination.
```

so then the code to write the fullName var to Firebase would be

```
newUserReference.setValue(
    [
     "eMail": self.EmailOu.text!,
     "firstName": self.NameOu.text!,
     "lastName": self.LastNameOu.text!,
     "studentId": self.StudentIDOu.text!,
     "Parking Zone": self.SignUpLabel.text!,
     "fullName": fullName,
     "uId": uidINT
    ]
)
```